# Is advanced indexing available across n-dimensions in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In PyTorch, we can use standard Pythonic indexing to apply advanced indexing across n-dimensions.

`preds` is a `Tensor` of shape `[1, 3, 64, 64, 12]`.

`a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are 1-dimensional `Tensor`s of the same length. In this instance that length is 9, but this is not always the case.

PyTorch example achieving the desired result:

```
result = preds[a, b, c, d]

result.shape
>>> [9, 12]
```

How can this be reproduced in TensorFlow, starting from the same 5 Tensors and creating the same output?

I have tried `tf.gather` whichs seem to be able to produce the same behaviour in a single dimension:

```
tf.shape(tf.gather(preds, a))
>>> [9, 3, 64, 64, 12]
```

Is it possible to extend this to eventually reach the desired output of shape `[9, 12]`?

I have also noted the presence of `tf.gather_nd` which seems like it may be relevant here but I cannot determine how I would employ it from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) can do that

```
t = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1,3,64,64,12))

# i_n = indices along n-th dim
i_1 = tf.constant([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
i_2 = tf.constant([0,1,2,1,2,2,1,0,0])
i_3 = tf.constant([0,21,15,63,22,17,21,54,39])
i_4 = tf.constant([0,16,26,51,33,45,48,29,1])
i = tf.stack([i_1, i_2, i_3, i_4], axis=1)  # i.shape == (9,4)

tf.gather_nd(t, i).shape   # (9,12)
```

Comment: This seems to produce exactly the behaviour I was looking for. Thanks! The `tf.stack` call seems to make all the difference - I had previously tried something similar but without that step to no avail

Comment: To visualize it, you can think of `i`'s last dimension i.e., `i.shape[-1]` as how "deep" you want to index into the tensor `t`, while all other dimensions up to the last i.e., `i.shape[:-1]` as the "batch dim" of the index tensor.  `i.shape == (9,4)` means you have a batch of 9 index tensors, each going 4-depth into `t`. Since `t` has 5 dmensions, going 4-depth means the last dimension of `t` will be extracted, and thus each index tensor will slice out an output tensor of shape 12, so 9 of them gives you `(9,12)`.